# Numbering a table in jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, html-table

I want to number the following table (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,...) 
My solution (var zaehler) shows a 2 every time ... what do I have to change? I also tried to define the variable zaehler outside the each.

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>    
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false&libraries=geometry"></script>
<br>
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="checkbox"> BMW 1er
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="checkbox"> BMW Active E
  </label>
  </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="checkbox"> BMW 1er Cabrio
  </label>
  </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="checkbox"> BMW X1
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="checkbox"> MINI
  </label>
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="checkbox"> MINI Clubman
  </label>
   <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="checkbox"> MINI Coupé
  </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="checkbox"> MINI Cabrio
  </label>
</div>
<br>
</head>
<body>
<font size="1"> 
<br>
<table class="table table-condensed" border="1" id="usertable"></table>
</font>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="alert alert-success">
  <a href="#" class="alert-link">Die Übersicht zu Drive-Now München lädt... Bitte einen Moment Geduld!</a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var zaehler=1;
$(document).ready(function(){
function callJSON() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $.getJSON('./url.php', function(data) {
            $ ("#usertable").empty();
            var cars = data.rec.vehicles.vehicles;
            //cars.sort(function(el1,el2){ return el1.model == el2.model ? 0 : (el1.model < el2.model ? -1 : 1); });
            cars.sort(function(el1, el2) {
            if(el1.model== el2.model) {
            if(el1.fuelState == el2.fuelState) {
            return 0;
            } else if(el1.fuelState < el2.fuelState) {
            return -1;
            } else {
            return 1;
            }
            } else if(el1.model < el2.model) {
            return -1;
            } else {
            return 1;
            }
            });

               $.each(cars, function(key, data){
                var laenge=cars.length;
                var vint=data.vin;
                var positionA= new google.maps.LatLng(data.position.latitude, data.position.longitude);
                var posiitonB= new google.maps.LatLng(48.1351253, 11.5819806);
                var entfernung= google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween (positionA, posiitonB);
                var entfernung1=(entfernung/1000);
                var entfernung2=entfernung1.toFixed(2);
                var entfernung3=entfernung2+" Km";
                console.log(entfernung2);
                console.log(positionA);
                console.log(posiitonB);
                var coopers="";
                var tanken="";
                var drive="MAN";
                var fuelfarbe="#01DF3A";
                var prozent="%";
                var kosten=" 31 Cent/Min "
                var tanksymbol="glyphicon-tint";
                var farbe="success";
                var flugbadge="";
                var mode="&dirflg=w";
                var kraftstoff="BENZIN";
                var ortbadge="glyphicon-map-marker";
                var entfernungsbadge="glyphicon-resize-horizontal";
                var krafts=" ("+data.fuelState+"%)";
                var strasse=data.address;
                var v=vint.substring(3,7);
                var pdf=vint.substring(10,17);
                var pdf1=pdf+".pdf";
                console.log(pdf);
                if(data.fuelType=="DDE"){kraftstoff="DIESEL";}
                if(v=="SX31"){coopers=" S";}
                if(v=="SW71"){coopers=" SD";}
                if(data.model=="BMW ActiveE "){tanksymbol="glyphicon-flash"; kraftstoff="STROM";}
                if(data.model=="BMW X1 "){kosten=" 34 Cent/Min ";}
                if(data.auto=="Y"){drive="AUT";}
                if((48.347910654607695 < data.position.latitude && data.position.latitude < 48.35988839686733)&&(11.781678199768066 < data.position.longitude && data.position.longitude < 11.792492866516113)){flugbadge="<span class='badge'>+12€</span>"; ortbadge="glyphicon-plane";}
                if(data.fuelState<=25){tanken="20 Freiminuten für Vollbetankung"; farbe="warning";}
                if(data.position.latitude=="0"){entfernung3="NaN"; strasse="Nicht lokalisierbar"; farbe="active";}
                $('#usertable').append(
                    function() {
                        return "<tr class="+farbe+">"+
                                    "<td>"+data.model+coopers+zaehler+"</td>"+
                                    "<td><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-user'></span> "+data.carName+"</td>"+
                                    //"<td><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-time'></span> "+dur+"</td>"+
                                    "<td>"+drive+"</td>"+
                                    "<td><span class='glyphicon "+tanksymbol+"'></span>" +kraftstoff+krafts+"</td>"+
                                    "<td>"+data.licensePlate+"</td>"+
                                    "<td><span class='glyphicon "+ortbadge+"'></span> "+strasse+"</td>"+
                                    "<td><span class='glyphicon "+entfernungsbadge+"'></span> "+entfernung3+"</td>"+
                                    "<td><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-euro'></span>"+kosten+flugbadge+"</td>"+
                                    "<td>"+laenge+"</td>"+
                                    "<td><a href='https://de.drive-now.com/php/metropolis/vehicle_details?vin="+ data.vin +"'target='_blank'><button class='btn btn-success btn-xs' type='button'>Reservieren</button></a></td>"+
                                    "<td><a href='http://maps.google.de/maps?saddr="+ posiitonB +"&daddr="+data.address+mode+"'target='_blank'><button class='btn btn-danger btn-xs' type='button'>Route</button></a></td>"+


                                    //"<td><img src='"+data.model+"1.png'/></td>"+
                                "<tr>"; 
                                zaehler++;
                    }
                );
            })
        }).always(callJSON);
    }, 2000);
    }
    $(callJSON);
    });
</script>
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-44913908-2', 'voltdrive.de');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure you have really defined it outside the `each` function ? Because it should work just fine [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tEzgP/)

Comment: Yes :/... look at my full code above.

Comment: And why for the love of God do you have elements inside your `head` tag ? [W3Schools#html_head](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_head.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define zaehler outside of the $.each loop. You are seeing 2 every time because every time you loop you are resetting zaehler to 1 and then adding 1. Also as cpreid mentioned you should also leave out the quotation marks.

```
var zaehler = 1;
$.each(cars, function(key, data){
     ....
    //use value of zaehler
    zaehler++;
}
```

Comment: "_I also tried to define the variable zaehler outside the each_" as he stated, that's confusing.

Comment: I noticed that after I posted, but there's no way it'd be 2 every time if it was declared outside of the loop...

Comment: @user2718017 It can't be. Are you sure you have zaehler declared **only** outside the loop ?

Comment: Ah ha! think i see it.  In your new code, you now have zaehler++ _inside_ the $('#usertable').append function, which means you will only add when the function is called. Move the zaehler++ down two lines so it is outside of the $('#usertable').append function.

Answer (score 0):

You definied zaehler as a string by wrapping it in double quotes

```
var zaehler="1";
zaehler++;
```

Just use

```
var zaehler = 1;
zaehler++;
```

Comment: That is really not the problem since JS will try to convert it to `Number` during `++` operation. `var x = "1"; x++;` results in 2, but `var x="1a"; x++;` results in `NaN`, since it could not be converted.